# Creating a filename in Python that begins with a variable instead of a string of characters

Tags: python, variables, filenames

I need to create a filename that looks like NAME_Forecast_DATE where name and date are variables. 
I have this so far 
    `filename = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\'+carrier +'_Forecast_'+date+'.xlsx'`

The problem is the last \ causes the +carrier+ to be a string of characters and *_Forecast_* to be a variable. 
How can I write this file name to the desktop when the name of the file starts with a variable?

Comment: Raw strings cannot end in a backslash (and I think that's in the documentation, so "officially so"). Why not simply use forwards slashes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\` instead of `\`

Example:

```
path = “C:\\” + something + “\\something”
```

Also you can use .format(), it’s a better way to format strings, but also keep using `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case, using the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method lets you see the string in a readable way without having to do any character escaping.

```py
filename = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\{}_Forecast_{}.xlsx'.format(carrier,date)
```

If you had a '\' at the end of the string, you would have to do string escaping with two backslashes and drop the raw string prefix, just as @nagyl suggests. Same goes for any of the other special characters that need escape string handling: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22